# Why i can not able to access my rails application db after establishing new connection to wordpress db manually?

Tags: database, wordpress, postgresql

I have a rails 4.2  application with postgres database which is running. I have requirement to connect with other databases (word_press_sites) on demand basis.

I have tried the below code this into rails console:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  "mysql2",
  host:     ENV["HOST"],
  username: ENV["USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["PASSWORD"],
  database: ENV["DB_NAME"]
)
```

above code results,
No error, connected to the word_press database_tables.

1) If am trying to access the table by calling User.all  in my rails application db i can not able to access which is throwing an error.

Answer (score 2):

After opening the rails console you can check

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database
```

This will give the current db info,Then try the script you have given

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    adapter:  "mysql2",
    host:     ENV["HOST"],
    username: ENV["USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["PASSWORD"],
    database: ENV["DB_NAME"]
)
```

Now try the same command

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database
```

**This will give the newly connected ActiveRecord connection
Which means Active record is shifted into newly connected wordpress database so that you can not able to access the table in your rails application database**

If you want to revert back to your rails app db you can do this

**`ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection( ActiveRecord::Base)`**

Let me know if you need more information